# Alpha, Beta, Delta, Theta Extraction from EEG signal using FFT in matlab

Tags: matlab

```matlab
%Convert data from EDF to MATLAB form
[header1, data1]=edfread('Subject00_1.edf');

%Sampling rate
Fs=500;

%Channel wise data extraction
data_ch1=data1(1,:);
data_ch1=data_ch1(1:length(data_ch1));

%Fourier Transform
fCoefsF=fft(data_ch1);

amplitude =abs(fCoefsF);

mirror_freq=length(amplitude)/2;

figure(1)
plot(amplitude)

%Manual Removal of higher Frequency
for i=1:length(fCoefsF)  
    
    if ((Fs/mirror_freq*i/2)>4)     %While extracting the Delta signal(upto 4hz)
        fCoefsF(i)=0;
        if length(fCoefsF)-i == 0
            break;
        end       
        fCoefsF(length(fCoefsF)-i)=0;
          
    else
        fCoefsF(i)=fCoefsF(i);
    end

end
amplitude=abs(fCoefsF);
figure(2)
plot(amplitude)

%Reconstruct the components of the EEG Signal
%Inverse fourier transform
component_recon=ifft(fCoefsF);
figure(3)
plot(component_recon)
```

I wanted to extract EEG components from EDF file. EEG Components are given in following table:

1. Delta - up to 4 Hz;
2. Theta - 4 -> 8 Hz;
3. Alpha - 8 -> 13 Hz;
4. Beta - 13 -> 30 Hz;

   I took help from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5901927/extracting-eeg-components-from-signal-within-matlab). But I don't know still why I am not getting the signal back while performing inverse fft.

Comment: please format your code appropriately

Comment: Formatting done.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this syntax to extract famous bands (Alpha, beta, theta...)

```
p = bandpower(x,fs,freqrange)
```

example: `p=bandpower(myEEG_channel,512,[0 4])`
in this example we calculate Delta band power from a channel of my EEG signal with fs=512 Hz.